# Berkeley CS169.1 MOOC Rotten Potatoes TDD Rspec Error Movie does not implement: <method>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to go through the Esaas examples of BerkeleyX CS169.1 MOOC class, TDD example using Rspec.  I am stuck with this error when I run rspec on my controller.

My rottenpotatoes/spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require_relative '../app/controllers/movies_controller.rb'


RSpec.describe MoviesController, type: :controller do
  describe 'searching TMDb' do
    it 'should call the model method that performs TMDb search' do
      allow(Movie).to receive(:show)
    end
  end
```

My rottenpotatoes/app/controllers/movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

end
```

running $ rspec /spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb' gives me the following error:

```
Failure/Error: allow(Movie).to receive(:show)
       Movie(id: integer, title: string, rating: string, description: text, release_date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) does not implement: show
```

An excerpt of my Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.3.2'
  gem 'ZenTest', '4.11.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels'
end
```

I've researched this thread [RSpec controller test error: controller does not implement method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904609/rspec-controller-test-error-controller-does-not-implement-method) and i don't think it's a instance vs class method issue.

Also I really should not need:

```
require_relative '../app/controllers/movies_controller.rb'
```

(due to "convention over configuration") in my rspec file, right?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this problem? having the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably looking for something like:

```
before(:each) do
  @results = [mock('movie_one'), mock('movie_two')]
end

it 'should call the model method that performs TMDb search' do
  Movie.should_receive(:find_in_tmdb).with('hardware').
    and_return(@results)
  post :search_tmdb, {:search_terms => 'hardware'}
end
```

which can be rewritten in RSpec 3 syntax as:

```
allow(Movie).to receive(:find_in_tmdb).with(hardware).and_return(@results)
```

Comment: I'm getting it from rspec:

Failure/Error:
       allow(Movie).to receive(:find_in_tmdb).with('hardware')
       .and_return(fake_results)
       Movie ... does not implement: find_in_tmdb

//   Since I'm testing the controller why is rspec caring about the implementation of the movie method?

Comment: Check that you have an instance method (def find_in_tmbd) defined in your Movie model that returns the correct return value. RSpec cares about the implementation of your model presumably because the controller action you are testing is calling something an instance method defined in your model.

Comment: That's exactly the problem in my opinion. From what I understand a controllers spec shouldnt care about the implementation of the model and the receive should override the method in place.